# LSTM prediction probability with sigmoid is low and so is AUC

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, auc

I have a **timeseries data** of **3228 Patients** and I am doing a disease (Sepsis) forecasting using `LSTM` [Functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) and my data looks like this. Access the whole data [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am1j7gBl276r-ycPXiUNcuohh4LT?e=dGT0Oy) and the whole code [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am1j7gBl276r-yi-sXA0nVq_P7tm?e=RUdfv9).

```
 HR     O2Sat   Temp    SBP      DBP    Resp    Age  Gender  ICULOS  SepsisLabel    P_ID
80.2    97.4    36.40   127.5   70.4    17.9    46     0        1         0        15888
95.0    97.0    36.85   102.5   63.4    30.0    46     0        2         0        15888
97.0    96.0    36.85   108.0   67.6    30.0    46     0        3         0        15888
97.0    95.0    37.04   102.0   63.1    32.0    46     0        4         0        15888
98.0    96.0    36.99   108.0   66.2    30.0    46     0        5         0        15888
```

My goal is to predict the `probability` of a patient of being Septic (SepsisLabel = 1) or Non-Septic (SepsisLabel = 0). So, I divided the data into `80:20` ratio with `2583 Patients for training` and `645 patients for testing` based on Patient ID. Then I converted them to `x-train, x-test, y-train, y-test` and then to `Multi-Index` dataframe so I can convert it to a `fixed length tensor` of `72` with `Post padding`. Now, each patient have its own tensor and these tensors are fed to LSTM model for making predictions. After training the model for `100 epochs`, the training accuracy is not increasing from `0.86`. I then predicted the model on test data and the prediction probabilities are very low, So is the AUC. Following is the code:

```
my_callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15),
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, monitor='val_accuracy'),
]
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
# es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)
# ckpt = ModelCheckpoint('modl.h5', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, monitor='val_accuracy')

# construct inputs
x = Input((None, x_train.shape[-1]) , name='input')
mask = Masking(0, name='input_masked')(x)

# stack LSTMs
lstm_kwargs = {'dropout': 0.20, 'recurrent_dropout': 0.1, 'return_sequences': True, 'implementation': 2}
lstm1 = LSTM(200, name='lstm1', **lstm_kwargs)(mask)
lstm2 = LSTM(200, name='lstm2', **lstm_kwargs)(lstm1)

btch = BatchNormalization()(lstm2)

# output: sigmoid layer
output = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'), name='output')(btch)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=output)

# compile model
optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# print layer shapes and model parameters
model.summary()

preds = model.predict(x_test)
# Output
array([[[0.17022534],
        [0.18894851],
        [0.20475313],
        ...,
        [0.2432414 ],
        [0.2432414 ],
        [0.2432414 ]],
        ...,
        [0.08733492],
        [0.08733492],
        [0.08733492]]], dtype=float32)
```

##### The AUC:

[image: AUC graph]

How I can improve the model to get higher probabilities and high AUC? I tried without `BatchNormalization()` but no increase in probabilities. I tried without `mask()`, I tried increasing `LSTM Layers`, I tried by changing optimizer to `Adam`, even changing `learning rate` but no better results.

Answer (score 1):

Had a look at your data and the reason you keep hitting `0.86` accuracy is that the incidence of the positives in your data is roughly ~14%. Accuracy is probably not the best metric to track here given the imbalance (perhaps area under precision-recall curve would be better). You might also try using the `sample_weight` argument of the `fit` function to weight your samples and counteract the imbalance issue.

Comment: Okay, so I should not calculate accuracy as you said. How I can find area under precision-recall curve? Also, talking about the prediction probabilities, How I can get higher probabilities?

Comment: so you can use `precision_recall_curve` from `sklearn.metrics` and feed the output into `auc` also from `sklearn.metrics`. Then wrap this in a `callback` (let me know if you need some help doing that and I can knock something together)

Comment: on the part, there are various ways to proceed - you can e.g. undersample the majority class, but it is not clear how that would work for seuqential data.

Comment: your best best is probably to adjust the probability decision threshold to be lower than 0.5 (much as is done to compute the ROC)

Comment: alternatively, try to add more discriminative features (or even include time-lagged target as a feature)

Comment: Can you please add some code so I can use `sample_weight` and `precision_recall_curve`?

Comment: can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

What I would try, but no promises :)
Feed the hidden layers of the LSTM into a dense layer and then to the binary output.